# Is there a better alternative for switch types with Cast

Tags: c#

Having following example:

```cs
public class Test{
    public Animal DoSomething(AnimalCreateDto animal){
        Animal created;
        if(animal is DogCreateDto dogCreateDto){
             Dog dog = new(dogCreateDto);
             created = Create(dog);
        }else if(animal is CateCreateDto catCreateDto){
             Cat cat = new(catCreateDto);
             created = Create(cat);
        }
        return created;
    }

    private Dog Create(Dog dog){ ... }
    private Cat Create(Cat cat){ ... }
}
```

Is there any way to use e.g. the switch-case?

Comment: https://badecho.com/index.php/2020/12/04/polymorphic-json-deserialization/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [pattern matching](https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2021/02/25/c-9-0-pattern-matching-in-switch-expressions/)

From the blog post above:

```
object obj = new Developer { FirstName = "Thomas", YearOfBirth = 1980 };

string favoriteTask;

switch (obj)
{
  case Developer dev when dev.YearOfBirth >= 1980 && dev.YearOfBirth <= 1989:
    // 1. This case is taken for the defined Developer object
    favoriteTask = $"{dev.FirstName} listens to heavy metal while coding";
    break;
  case Developer dev: 
    // 2. This case matches too, but it's defined after the first one that matches
    favoriteTask = $"{dev.FirstName} writes code";
    break;
  case Person _: 
    // 3. This case matches too for a Developer, as Person is a base class
    favoriteTask = "Eat and sleep";
    break;
  default:
    favoriteTask = "Do what objects do";
    break;
}
```

Comment: That's not pattern matching. At least not the newer version

Comment: @JHBonarius It does use pattern matching. `case Developer` is pattern matching.

Comment: Yes, but there is little direct value from that feature for the OP this way.

Comment: Is there also any variant for Entity-Framework and LINQ?

Answer (score 2):

Declare an abstract method in the base type and implement it in child types.

```
abstract class AnimalCreateDto
{
    public abstract Animal Create();
}

class DogCreateDto : AnimalCreateDto
{
    public override Animal Create() { /* Create Dog */ }
}

class CatCreateDto : AnimalCreateDto
{
    public override Animal Create() { /* Create Cat */ }
}

public Animal DoSomething(AnimalCreateDto animal)
    => animal.Create();
```

Comment: Nah, that's just an alternative approach. A more traditional object oriented one. But function overloading is just as good if it works. It's a more open-closed principle approach actually. And this is not what the OP is asking

Comment: Plus we now would use an interface for this, instead of an abstract class.

Comment: What the OP is asking I think is a better alternative, switch-case or switch-expression is also an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The latest pattern matching (C#9) style would be

```
public Animal DoSomething(AnimalCreateDto animal) =>
    animal switch
    {
        DogCreateDto dto => Create(new Dog(dto)),
        CateCreateDto dto => Create(new Cat(dto)),
        _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
    };
```